# php counter avoid refresh

Tags: php, counter

there!I write a piece of code to counter the vistor of my site with no refresh.the following is my code,can anyone give me some tips about the code and give some recommendation?

```
<?php

    $counterFile='counter.txt';
    $ipFile='ip.txt';
    if(!is_file($counterFile)){
        file_put_contents($counterFile,0);
    }
    if(!is_file($ipFile)){
        file_put_contents($ipFile,0);
    }


    $handle=fopen($counterFile,'rb') or die('error:can not open the counter file');
    $fileSize=filesize($counterFile);
    $counter=intval(fread($handle,$fileSize));
    fclose($handle);
    /**----$counter=file_get_contents($counterFile);----***/

    $oldIp=file_get_contents($ipFile);
    $currIp=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    //echo $oldIp.'==='.$currIp;


    if($oldIp!=$currIp){
        ++$counter;
        $handle=fopen($counterFile,'wb');
        fwrite($handle,$counter);
        fclose($handle);
        /**----file_put_contents($counterFile,$counter);----***/
    }


    file_put_contents($ipFile,$currIp);


    echo $counter;

?>
```

Comment: OMFG.  People still do counters?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review and thusly better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Why not use something like Google Analytics for web stats?

Comment: @JohnGreen Sure. It's just that most people tend to count more stuff nowadays. [Measure everything!](http://codeascraft.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Google Analytics or a basic stats package. or you can track them through the ip addresses, where one person from one ip address is one visitor. or you can use cookies where you can set a cookie on visitor first request so you identify further request as coming from the same visitor

Comment: IP address isn't a good solution. You may have 50 different people on the same external IP address in an office and that would only count once.

Comment: so i would say use google analytics . this is the best solution you can get.

Comment: I write this code  just for pratice,but still tank you very much!you give me some tips!

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize object on destruct by the magic method [__destruct](http://php.net/__destruct) and make a static function that gives new instance of the unserialized one if exists :

```
<?php

class Counter {
   const CACHE_FILE = '/tmp/counter.clss';
   protected $_counter = 0;
   public function up(){
     $this->_counter++;
   }

   public function down(){
     $this->_counter--;
   }

   public function howmany(){
     print $this->_counter;
   }

   public function __destruct(){
     file_put_contents(self::CACHE_FILE,serialize($this));
   }

   public static function retrieve(){
     if(file_exists(self::CACHE_FILE)){
       $obj = unserialize(file_get_contents(self::CACHE_FILE));
     }else{
       $obj = new self;
     }
     return $obj;
   }
}
$ctr = Counter::retrieve();
$ctr->up();
$ctr->howmany();
```

Then call the file, if the temporal file exists, will recreate object and then sum counter :

```
~$ php counter.php
1
~$ php counter.php
2
~$ php counter.php
3
```